# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /personalInformation/show

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grails, groovy, syntax

I have seen many posts with this same error, but I have not found one that is similar to mine. My issue seems simple, but I don't understand why it is happening.

The error printing in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /personalInformation/show
```

This is my button that I click to receive the error:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:-8px;"><g:img  uri="/img/scholarship_search.png" class="checkMarkPosition"/></div>
    <a href="/personalInformation/show" data-toggle="tab">Personal Information</a>
</div>
```

It doesn't make any sense to me because I can type in the address myurl/personalInformation/show and get to the page without any problem. Any help on the matter is appreciated!

Comment: Nothing's wrong with that. When do you get that error message?

Comment: Where is the error message occurring?

Comment: Could it be that its missing an extension at the end? something like `.html`?

Comment: I get the message as soon as i click on the "button" as im calling it I show above.

Comment: "The error printing in the console" the Grails console, or the Javascript console in your browser?

We might need to see the whole source of the GSP/HTML page. The problem could be earlier in your code.

Comment: If you could update with the full stacktrace, that'd be helpful also

Comment: It is difficult to say from the snippet posted but it looks like you might have mismatched `div` tags.  You have 1 opening and 2 closing.  In the larger context than that posted do you have some things mismatched in a way that might be confusing the GSP compiler?

Comment: Ill have to check on the div tags + make sure theres no other mismatch tags when I can. Also, the error is printing in the chrome console. next chance I get I will update my issue here with more info.